# Using autolayout from code with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm trying to use autolayout FROM CODE to correctly handle rotation in my UIScrollView that contains many UILabel generated at runtime for every page of a UIPageControl.

I've not found so many examples, so i ask if anyone has examples about UIScrollView with autolayout with NSLayoutConstraints.

**EDITED**
To be clearer: i create at runtime different UILabels and add them to UIScrollView. In portrait it's:

[image]
<sub>(source: [disclafani.org](http://www.disclafani.org/1a.png))</sub>

While in landscape is wrong:
[image]
<sub>(source: [disclafani.org](http://www.disclafani.org/2a.png))</sub>

How can it be solved using autolayout? I've tried using:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *cons1=[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintWithItem:label 
attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft          
relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
toItem:label2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft 
multiplier:1.0 
constant:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width*-1
                          ];
```

but it does not work and i don't think this is the right approach

Comment: Did you even look at the code examples I pointed you to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually two quite different strategies, which Apple describes in great detail in [this article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html), and which I illustrate in these two examples:

- https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/iOS6bookExamples/ch20p573scrollViewAutoLayout
- https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/iOS6bookExamples/ch20p573scrollViewAutoLayout2

Keep in mind, though, that UILabel is a very special case, because of its use of instrinsic size rules. It is hard to say more without knowing more details of your case.

Comment: these links are now broken. Can you paste the answer here instead?

Comment: The book went on to another edition, for iOS 7. All the iOS 6 book examples are still there, but moved; just add "iOS6bookExamples" before the name of the project (as I've now done).